# Isomorphism of linear map with conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose $V$ is a 3 -dimensional vector space and let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map such that $T^{3}=0$ and $T^{2} \neq 0$.

Show that ${Id }-T$ is an isomorphism. Express its inverse in terms of powers of $T$.

So if I come up with its inverse is it true that it is an isomorphism. Otherwise how to show this.

Comment: What is your definition of isomorphism?

Comment: If map is both injective and surjective then it becomes isomorphism.

Comment: So maybe your question is: if a map has an inverse then is it injective and surjective? For finite dimensional vectorspaces if $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear map and $S: V \rightarrow V$ is another linear map such that $S \circ T = T \circ S = Id$ then $T$ and $S$ are both isomophisms

Comment: @OliverClarke but that is true invertible map is both injective and surjective as far as finite dimensional space.

Comment: In general for linear maps you need to show that an inverse exists on both sides, see previous comment. But for finite dimensional vector spaces it suffices to show that an inverse exists on one side.

Answer (score 1):

If you can show that there exists a linear map $P$ such that $T \circ Q = Q \circ T = \text{Id}$, then you have that $T$ is invertible, and for $V$ a finite dimensional vector space, $Q$ is an isomorphism.

**Hint:** Consider $P = 1 + T + T^2$, what can you say about $T \circ Q$ and $Q \circ T$ where $Q = \text{Id} - T$

Comment: But we have map Id - T so how do we compose it with P ?

Comment: I have edited my answer and made it more clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Related to the comments on the OP and definitions of isomorphisms of vectorspaces.

If $V$ is a finite dimensional vectorspace and $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear map,
then the following are equivalent:

- $T$ is an isomorphism, i.e. injective and surjective. (*)
- $T$ is injective.
- $T$ is surjective.
- There exists a linear map $S : V \rightarrow V$ such that $T \circ S = S \circ T = Id$. (*)
- There exists a linear map $S : V \rightarrow V$ such that $S \circ T = Id$.
- There exists a linear map $S : V \rightarrow V$ such that $T \circ S = Id$.

For vectorspaces in general, possibly infinite dimensional, then the starred statements are equivalent.

The other thing that might be useful for the question is if $A, B$ and $C$ are linear maps from $V$ to $V$ then composition distributes over addition, i.e. $A \circ (B + C) = (A \circ B) + (A \circ C)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ denote the minimal polynomial of $T$. Let $q$ be the polynomial $q(x)=x^3$, then $q(T)=0$ and therefore, $p$ divides $q$ and so $0$ is the only root of $p$, possibly repeated.So, there are no other eigenvalues of Id-$T$ except for $1-0=1$. Further, a linear operator S is invertible if and only if all its eigenvalues are nonzero.